# Property 'run' does not exist on type 'Promise<FindNftsByOwnerOutput>'

Tags: web3.js, metaplex, nft, solana-wallet-adapter, metaplex-js

I want to get Nft data from metaplex but i wanna know what does .run() work here and why .run() method does not exist here

const nfts = await metaplex.nfts().findAllByOwner({owner: args.publicKey,}).run()

nfts.forEach(nft => {
metaplex.nfts()
.load({metadata: nft})
.run()
.then(loaded => console.log(loaded))

Answer (score 1):

`run()` is only necessary for builders, not for operations.
Builders are available for operations that write to the chain, and allow several operations to be combined into a single transaction.

See:

- [`NftClient`](https://metaplex-foundation.github.io/js/classes/js.NftClient.html)
- [`NftBuildersClient`](https://metaplex-foundation.github.io/js/classes/js.NftBuildersClient.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `@metaplex-foundation/js` package is also now deprecated in favor of, UMI (Unified Metaplex Interface)

See repo here https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/umi